# SQL query to search in a concated string

Tags: mysql, database

In a database i have a table `prospect` and has two columns `firstname` and `lastname`.

Now the issue is that i want to search in both columns; the easy solution would be to use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `prospect` WHERE lastname like '%piece of lastname%' or firstname like '%piece of firstname%'
```

This however requires to have two search fields, firstname and lastname. I want that users can search in one field. How should a query look like when I want to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to search the concatenation of two fields? Then you can use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM prospect
WHERE CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) LIKE '%ohn Smit%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM prospect
WHERE firstname + ' '+ lastname LIKE '%name%'
```