# Sqlite Query to search in a combination of several columns concated to on string

Tags: sqlite

I am stuck with a query in an Sqlite Database.
The complete table structure is a bit complex so I will make an example that is broken down to my Problem.
I have 2 tables like

```
T1
_id       name      v1        v2        v3
1         test      4         3         1
2         to        1         2         2
3         show      2         2         2
4         what      4         2         4
5         I         1         1         1
6         mean      3         3         1

T2
_id       name
1         this
2         is
3         a
4         test
```

v1, v2, v3 are the foreign keys of T2 _id and in combination will result in one string.

In this example:

T1 _id 1: testathis
T1 _id 2: thisisis
T1 _id 3: isisis
T1 _id 4: testistest
T1 _id 5: thisthisthis
T1 _id 6: aatest

And in this resulting string I want to search and get a result table.
For example if the search string is "isi" (in the sql query "%isi%") I want to get a result table like this:

```
name   v1v2v3
to     thisisis
show   isisis
```

It is propably quit easy but I am totally stuck here.
I tried already several ways including **group_concat()** and various combinations of **select   ... where** clauses.
Although I tried a query similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956395/sql-query-to-search-in-a-concated-string) one. 
But I am allways failing on the fact that the string has to be concated from rows of another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  T1.name as name,
  tmpV1.name || tmpV2.name || tmpV3.name as v1v2v3
FROM
  T1
JOIN
  T2 as tmpV1 on T1.v1 = tmpV1._id 
JOIN
  T2 as tmpV2 on T1.v2 = tmpV2._id 
JOIN
  T2 as tmpV3 on T1.v3 = tmpV3._id
WHERE
  v1v2v3 like '%isi%'
;
```

Edit: aww Mosty beat me.

Answer (score 2):

Karl, give this is try:

```
select t1.name, t21.name || t22.name || t23.name as v1v2v3 from t1
join t2 t21 on t1.v1 = t21._id
join t2 t22 on t1.v2 = t22._id
join t2 t23 on t1.v3 = t23._id
where t21.name || t22.name || t23.name like '%isi%'
```

I don't have SQLite to test it right now, but it should work :)